# Chosen.js multiple select values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.js to create a multiple select, but instead of processing the form in php, I am trying to use javascript to parse the values. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to retrieve the values from the multiple select.

I create the select with:

```
<select data-placeholder="Select a category..." name="categories[]" multiple style="width: 350px" class="chzn-select">
```

and attempt to get the selected values using these javascript calls:

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen().val();
```

returns null

and

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen().val(0);
```

returns

`{"0":{"jQuery19109988393174677814":730},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":       {"jQuery19109988393174677814":1,"location":{}},"context":{"jQuery19109988393174677814":1,"location":{}},"length":1},"context":{"jQuery19109988393174677814":1,"location":{}},"selector":".chzn-select"}`

using `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mixed the use of `chosen()` and `val()`.

The former transforms your `select` into a nice multiple select list, while the latter gets you the value(s) of the selected element(s).

So your JavaScript code would be:

```
// Transforms your select element
$(".chzn-select").chosen();

// Gets the selected value(s)
$(".chzn-select").val();
```

The `val()` method will return [an array containing each selected option](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

I quickly created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRCyq/) to show you how to use the plugin: when you click on the button, you will see the selected values in the console.